# Search through multiple ElementTypes

Tags: plugin-development, search, elementcriteriamodel

Is it possible to search through multiple ElementTypes?

Instead of this:

```
craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry)->limit(10)->search('Test');
```

Doing something like this:

```
craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry, ElementType::Asset, ElementType::Category)->limit(10)->search('Test');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to do the in multiple queries at this point.

Consider voting for this [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/9505794-all-search-to-work-across-element-types-particul), which is asking for what you're looking for.